# git add very slow with ultra large folders with more than 1 million files

Tags: git

I have a folder with more than 1 million files.

When I want to add a single file to a commit, say `git add data/foo.json`, it is very slow.

The reason is that `git add data/foo.json` makes a stat system call on `data` (as for `git status`), and this call is itself very slow due to the number of files.

Why does `git add` internally makes this stat call? Is there a workaround?

Comment: best workaround: make subfolders and ignore those